# str_replace matches incorrect of array

Tags: php, str-replace

My code is

```
$detail='[rollno],[name]';
$details=explode(",", $detail);
$msg="Your rollno is [rollno], Your name is [name] Thanks ";
print str_replace($details, array("abc", "1225"), $msg );
echo "<br/>";
print str_replace($details, array("xyz", "1335"), $msg );
echo "<br/>";
```

Output is :

```
Your rollno is abc, Your name is 1225 Thanks 
Your rollno is xyz, Your name is 1335 Thanks 

Array ( [0] => [rollno] [1] => [name] )
```

I am not able to print correct sequence of name and rollno if the details variable sequence is same as above

Comment: Array ( [0] => [rollno] [1] => [name] ) ? What is that? You are declaring the array like that?

Comment: yes, i want to declare like that.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets [ ] are a shortcut to create an array, so what you are doing here is:

`array(array(0) => array(rollno) array(1) => array(name));`

That is wrong syntax.

You must wrap [] with "" or else PHP will think you are trying to create an array.

Maybe you should try this:

```
$details = ["[rollno]", "[name]"];
```

or

```
$details = array("[rollno]","[name]");
```

PHP will automatically set the numerical keys to 0 and 1.

Comment: "encapsulate" isn't appropriate word here, because it's about OOP's theory

Comment: I have the array type of this $details = array("[rollno]","[name]"); but the output is showing wrong

Comment: Have you tried replacing the brackets? $details=array("%rollno%","%name%"). and $msg =  $msg="Your rollno is %rollno%, Your name is %name% Thanks ";